# A Precalculus Question...

Tags: inverse-function

If f(x)=x^2+1, then (f o f)(x)=?

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}{ccc} 
(f\circ f)(x) = f(f(x)) &=& (f(x))^2 + 1 \\ &=& (x^2 +1)^2 +1 \\ &=& x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 + 1 \\ &=& x^4 + 2x^2 + 2 \end{array}$